# Как получить из матрицы все диагонали на Python?

Tags: python, матрицы

Как можно из любой квадратной матрицы получить все диагонали? Пока не очень понимаю как это сделать.

Пример матрицы:

```
[[0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0]]
```

Пример вывода диагоналей:

```
[[0],
[1, 1],
[0, 0, 0],
[1,0],
[0]]
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код для вывода главной диагонали.

Comment: Для чего?
Вот главная диагональ - [matrix[i][i] for i in range(len(matrix))]

Comment: Что бы вопрос не закрыли из-за отсутствия вашей попытки решить задачу. Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: Добавьте туда же кода для вывода диагонали соседней с главной. Скажем, той что над ней.